# Best-practice place to put custom Python exceptions which are only raised by a specific class

Tags: python

I want to write some custom exceptions which are only raised by a specific python class, but there are potentially two ways of doing this. I could do it as part of the module itself:

```
class FooException(Exception):
    pass

class FooClass():
    def something():
        # code
        raise FooException("something went wrong")
```

or, I could nest it within the class itself:

```
class FooClass():
    class FooException(Exception):
        pass

    def something():
        # code
        raise FooException("something went wrong")
```

I would personally prefer the second, since it seems cleaner to make the connection between the exception and the class that it is pertinent to explicit, but there are some disadvantages. For instance, if you subclass FooClass:

```
class BarClass(FooClass):
    pass
```

it is now possible to refer to FooClass.FooException as BarClass.BarException as well.

Is there a Pythonic best-practice for this? I have looked around a little, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Do you mean they will only ever be *raised* within the class or will they also only ever be *caught* within the class?

Comment: They will only ever be raised from within the class, but may be caught from outside.

Comment: Since code outside the class might want to catch the exception, it's *not* only used by the class.

Comment: Good point. I've edited the post to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep exceptions at the module (global) level.  Nesting them inside the classes just makes more work for anyone wanting to use your class:

```
try:
    FooClass().something()
except FooClass.FooException:
    pass
```

That's repitition for no good purpose.